# Error: Out of bounds Java Bubble sort

Tags: java, sorting, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public void sort()  // pulls the numbers off the stack then orders them, putting back onto stack in order. 
                    // Does not care where the it left off. Note: making a temp varible for the new head will head. 
                    // once the old head hits a -1; or a value less than it self it will start from the "sort head"
                    // ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
{
     int[] numbers = new int[node - 1];    //everything else should be working fine. 

     for(int i = size ; i > 1; i--)        //for loop for the numberof/size of the elements needed to be sorted.3
     {
         int temphead = head;

         numbers[i] = (stack.getpeople(temphead));  // pulls a value for a stack

         temphead = stack.getBLink(temphead);       // pulls that values back link and adds it to the new lead.
     }

    int tempVar;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) //used for bubble sort.
    {
             for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length - 1; j++) // used for bubble sort.
             {
                     if(numbers[i] > numbers[j + 1]) //ERROR HERE Out of bounds
                     {
                     tempVar = numbers [j + 1];      //ERROR HERE Out of bounds
                     numbers [j + 1] = numbers [i];  //ERROR HERE Out of bounds
                     numbers [i] = tempVar;          //ERROR HERE Out of bounds
                     }
             }
    }
    int temphead = head;

    for(int i = size ; i > 1; i--)
    {
        stack.getpeople(temphead = numbers[i]); //adds the sorted list back to the stack 
        temphead = stack.getBLink(temphead); //resets the temp head. 

    }
}
```

//The above is error is marked out of bounds. it is probably something really simple that i missing, I do not believe it is the bubble sort function it self due to the fact that the logic is right? however it may be an outbound error do to a condensation not programmed in my stack, if that is the case i will have to update this post with the stack and some of the other methods. -----Thanks for the help,

Comment: +1 Because two of the [hardest problems](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) in computer science are cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 2):

The error is one line before you think -

```
for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length - 1; j++) { // <--- The error was here.
  // used for bubble sort.
  if(numbers[i] > numbers[j + 1]) // When j = (number.length - 1) [0 based indexing], 
                                  // then j + 1 = (number.length) and that is 
                                  // out of bounds.
```

Comment: Assuming this was it, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer. Otherwise, please post what you did to fix it - and accept that.

Answer (score 0):

when you call numbers[j+1] you are going out of bounds on the array.